# How can you trigger a function if one checkbox out of multiple checkboxes is clicked

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am creating a Todo app and I need to trigger a function (which counts number of checkboxes checked) when any one of the checkboxes is checked.

I am unable to get an onlick event to happen if a checkbox is clicked. I have manage to do it with a submit button, but not with the checkbox itself

```
//the html
<div class="flow-right controls">
        <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
        <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
      </div>
      <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
      <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
    </div>

// the function above this one creates the checkbox and appends it to the list in the HTML
const box = document.createElement('INPUT');
      box.type = "checkbox";
      box.name = "countme";
      box.id = "checkme"
      li.appendChild(box);

// this is the code I have created to trigger a function unchecked which returns the count of unchecked checkboxes.

let getcheck = document.getElementsByName("countme");
for (let i = 0; i < getcheck.length; i++) {
   getcheck[i].onClick = unchecked;
 }
```

Nothing is happening so I am unsure with how to debug this

Comment: What is `unchecked`? Also you need to do something like `getcheck[i].addEventListener('click', function() {});`

Comment: Thanks Arup. I used the method prescribed by Aimal below and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need this

```js
function newTodo() {
  let ulElement = document.getElementById('todo-list');
  let todoElement = document.createElement('li');
  const box = document.createElement('INPUT');
      box.type = "checkbox";
      box.name = "countme";
      box.id = "checkme";
      box.value = 0;
      todoElement.appendChild(box);
  const span = document.createElement('span').TEXT_NODE = 'To do task';
  todoElement.append(span);
  ulElement.append(todoElement);
  let unCheckELement = document.getElementById('unchecked-count');
  unCheckELement.textContent = parseInt(unCheckELement.textContent) + 1;
  box.onchange = onCheckboxCheck;
}
function onCheckboxCheck(element) {
  let count = parseInt(document.getElementById('item-count').textContent);
  count += element.srcElement.checked ? 1 : -1;
  let allElements = document.querySelectorAll('#todo-list li').length;
  document.getElementById('item-count').textContent = count;
  document.getElementById('unchecked-count').textContent = allElements - count;

}
```

```html
<div class="flow-right controls">
    <span>Item count: <span id="item-count">0</span></span>
    <span>Unchecked count: <span id="unchecked-count">0</span></span>
  </div>
    <button class="button center" onClick="newTodo()">New TODO</button>
    <ul id="todo-list" class="todo-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Aimal!! This worked wonders. I changed it a bit because I wanted my Todo count to go up everytime someone added a checkbox. I did this by declaring let count =  0 on top of the script and commenting out the //document.getElementById('item-count').textContent = count; I also added a counter in the newTodo function which edits the inner HTML of the Item Count.. but all in all your solution worked well. Thanks

Comment: Edit: I added the following in the newTodo function (similar to what you have done for unchecked count) itemCountSpan.textContent = parseInt(itemCountSpan.textContent) + 1.. where itemCountSpan is the getElementbyId('item-count').  So that the code is more consistent.

Comment: Question: for todoElement - why have you used let and not Cons as I had done earlier?